# Magnetic fields and forces, Gravitation fields and forces

Tags: electromagnetism, gravity

Is a current carrying wire affected by the magnetic field that it produces? In other words, will a current carrying wire be acted on by a magnetic force produces by its own magnetic fields?

Is a mass affected by its own gravitational field?

Comment: The answer to all three questions is yes. In the case of the electric wire, the force should (I think?) cancel out to zero, and it also gives rise to a weak phenomenon called the self-Hall effect. In the case of gravity, a mass is held together to some extent by the force of its own gravity.

Comment: How come the forces cancel out to zero for the current carrying wire? Do you use F=ILB?